# Orthogonality and linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra

I do not understand a simple problem:

$ W = Span{(-\frac{1}2,\frac{1}2,\frac{1}2,-\frac{1}2),(\frac{1}2,\frac{1}2,-\frac{1}2,-\frac{1}2)}$

Find vector u in W, and v in $W^{\perp}$ such that u+v=(1,1,1,1)

The problem is that when I find vectors in $W^{\perp}$ there is no way I can find a linear combination with any vector in W that would equal (1,1,1,1)

Also, if a I want to find a point in W closest to P = (0,12,12,12)
Do I just find  $projection_wP$

Comment: Isn't $(1,1,1,1)\in W^\perp$?

Comment: Also, yes, you do

Comment: Ok thanks let me try to think of this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both questions are asking about the image of the given vector under the orthogonal projection to the subspace $W$.

Draw (schematically) the first one: $u$ is going to be just the projection of $t:=(1,1,1,1)$, and then $t-u$ is going to be orthogonal to $W$, so will be good for $v$.

In general, to find the projection of a given vector $t$ to the subspace $W$ spanned by *mutually orthogonal unit vectors* $\langle w_1,w_2,..\rangle$ (like in our case), consider 
$$u:=\langle t,w_1\rangle w_1+\langle t,w_2\rangle w_2+\dots$$
and $v:=t-u$, and check that $\langle v,w_i\rangle=0$, i.e. $v\in W^\perp$.

Comment: Ok thanks let me just try to imagine this.

Comment: Just draw it with general vectors (in the plane) $t=u+v$ with $W$ a given line.

Comment: Oh okay I think I get it. Both questions are essentially the same. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. $\,\,\!\!$

Comment: If $W$ were given in another way, for this projection method  you have to find an orthonormal basis for $W$ first, *or*, perhaps easier, write $u=\alpha_1w_1+\alpha_2w_2+\dots$ and calculate $\alpha_i$ by the equations $\langle (t-u),w_i\rangle=0$.